# Dated protobuf version in Anymote Library

Tags: protocol-buffers, google-tv

in our app we are using Protocol buffer version 2.4.1. Now i wanted to integrate some 2. screen functionality and get an builderror because of a duplicate library when i add the Anymote-library. The Anymote-Lib uses protocollbuffers in version 2.2.0. Replacing it with the newer version in the Anymote-lib results in an error:

> 08-28 19:47:40.967: E/AndroidRuntime(32461): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.polo.wire.protobuf.PoloProto$PairingRequest
>   08-28 19:47:40.967: E/AndroidRuntime(32461):    at com.google.polo.wire.protobuf.ProtobufWireAdapter.toProto(ProtobufWireAdapter.java:299)
>   08-28 19:47:40.967: E/AndroidRuntime(32461):    at com.google.polo.wire.protobuf.ProtobufWireAdapter.poloMessageToProto(ProtobufWireAdapter.java:277)
>   08-28 19:47:40.967: E/AndroidRuntime(32461):    at com.google.polo.wire.protobuf.ProtobufWireAdapter.sendMessage(ProtobufWireAdapter.java:245)
>   08-28 19:47:40.967: E/AndroidRuntime(32461):    at com.google.polo.pairing.PairingSession.sendMessage(PairingSession.java:675)
>   08-28 19:47:40.967: E/AndroidRuntime(32461):    at com.google.polo.pairing.ClientPairingSession.doInitializationPhase(ClientPairingSession.java:63)
>   08-28 19:47:40.967: E/AndroidRuntime(32461):    at com.google.polo.pairing.PairingSession.doPair(PairingSession.java:390)
>   08-28 19:47:40.967: E/AndroidRuntime(32461):    at com.example.google.tv.anymotelibrary.connection.ConnectingTask.attemptToPair(ConnectingTask.java:262)
>   08-28 19:47:40.967: E/AndroidRuntime(32461):    at com.example.google.tv.anymotelibrary.connection.ConnectingTask.connect(ConnectingTask.java:196)
>   08-28 19:47:40.967: E/AndroidRuntime(32461):    at com.example.google.tv.anymotelibrary.connection.ConnectingTask.run(ConnectingTask.java:172)

@Megha Joshi: Could you please update the Anymote library to use the actual protobuf version or is there any other way to solve this? Right now the library is just not usable for us.

Answer (score 0):

Please file a bug in :
http://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/

I will look into it this week.

Comment: Thx, i filed it in the issuetracker: http://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/issues/detail?id=75